# How to show link to all objects with same foreign key from Django Admin change page

Tags: django, hyperlink, foreign-keys, django-admin, inline

I am trying to link directly from the change page of a Company Year in Django Admin to the other changepages of Company Year that have the same Company as a foreign key.

Currently I have a link from the change page to the company page, and there I have links to all Company Years related to this company. However, it would be better if you could switch directly between the years without going to the company page first.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CompanyYear(models.Model):
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   year = models.IntegerField()
```